# how to obtain csrf token when make a Corona sdk POST request on Django

Tags: django, post, request, coronasdk, csrf

I am trying to send (POST) a JSON data using Corona SDK to a Django server. However, I always get the CSRF token error.

I understand that I will need to post the CSRF token to the django server when I make the post request from Corona. But question is how can I obtain the token in Corona in the first place?

According to Django Doc, one can get CSRF token from cookie. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-ajax
One can also use @csrf_except decorator. But i wonder if there is a way to solve this without using the decorator?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- Maybe, there is no need for your **APP** to use csrf protection.
- Django is a web framework, and the csrf occurs in web sit, not in mobile APP.
- CSRF: Cross-site request forgery.
- > CSRF exploits the trust that a site has in a user's browser
- [wiki](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cross-site_request_forgery)
- You can see this post bellow
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25080625/1474823m

Comment: Thanks. I hope the message is officially confirmed. I've been trying to solve this for ages.

Comment: +1 to this. Unless your app involves authenticating users using a session cookie, your users aren't going to be vulnerable to CSRF. Using the ```@csrf_exempt``` decorator for this view is probably your best bet

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your options are:

1. Use the jQuery cookie plugin to get the csrf token on the frontend. The link you referenced gives you code that you can pretty much copy & paste.
2. Write a custom middleware hook on the backend to grab the csrf token from the request. This is easier than it sounds, but it's a little counter-intuitive, because the csrftoken cookie is only available in the `request` object during the response part of the request-response cycle. You'll need to define a class in a file called `middleware.py` and override `process_response`:

   ```
   class CSRFHook(object):

       def process_response(self, request, response):

           csrf_token = request.COOKIES['csrftoken']

           # Do something with csrf_token here

           return response
   ```

   Then add `CSRFHook` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py`:

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
       ...
       'middleware.CSRFHook',
   )
   ```

   It doesn't matter where your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` you put your custom middleware. But remember that middleware classes are executed in top-down order during the request half of the cycle and bottom-up in the response half.

Comment: 1. thanks for the answer. I am really not quite confident on creating a middleware class. Not really understand how it works. 2. I am actually very surprised that no other easier solutions on this topic. Do people never use corona SDK with Django????

Comment: for your first comments about using jQuery cookie plugin. Is there a specific version for corona? I can't seem to find anything...

Comment: Probably not. I've never worked with Corona, but I imagine your solution will probably depend on the platform you're developing for. You'll want to find a library for your platform that allows you to submit an initial GET request. The response from that request should include a csrftoken cookie. Then you'll need a way to parse out the cookie from the response. May I ask, what platform are you developing for?

Comment: corona is cross platform. I actually got 2 solution. One is to forget about the token, because some say it is not required for mobile request. The other one is to get the token in the server and return it in the response. So I get the token in the response but not from cookie. Not sure if this is safe enough though.